# Python error when entering sudo mode

Tags: python, sudo

I have just booted my 2 year old Ubuntu 18.04 laptop and when I enter `sudo` mode to run updates, I get the following error:

```
File "/lib/security/howdy/compare.py", line 17, in <module>
import dlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib'
Unknown error: 1
```

The commands that follow still run, just a little frustrating to see this error fill up the terminal window every time...

Please, does anyone know what is the cause of this?

Comment: Did you create that python script? It's not part of a stock install.

Comment: Looks like you installed "howdy" which is like Windows Hello for Linux. Perhaps remove it if it isn't working?

Comment: Did that and it worked. Silly me!

Answer (score 3):

**A2A**
: Figured it out just now.

Turns out the last time I used this laptop, I was attempting to get the built-in fingerprint sensor to work. The laptop in question being a Dell Latitude E5570, there are no drivers available for Ubuntu for the fingerprint reader.

I removed the file located in `/lib/security/howdy/compare.py` forcefully and the error then became clearer: unable to load "howdy".

I went and removed this "howdy" module, and ran `apt autoremove` and purged the package cache. It appears to have solved the issue, as I am now no longer getting the error on launch of `sudo` command.